# angular http post error 415 .net core web api

Tags: angular, api, http, asp.net-core, post

hi i need some help regarding posting to .net core web api. i am new to angular.

im trying to post a request at https://localhost:44394/api/SyUsers
but i get 415 error i tried to set
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

here is the post method:

```
  addPost(
    authType: string,    
    userId: string,
    userCreateDate: any,
    username: string,
    firstName: string,
    middleName: string,
    lastName: string,
    email: string,
    position: string,
    section: string,
    department: string,
    alias01: string,
    alias02: string,
    alias03: string,
    alias04: string,
    userModifiedDate: any
    ) {
    const userData = new FormData();
    userData.append('authType', authType);
    userData.append('userId', userId);
    userData.append('userCreateDate', userCreateDate);
    userData.append('username', username);
    userData.append('Hash', localStorage.getItem('userId').toString());
    userData.append('firstName', firstName);
    userData.append('middleName', middleName);
    userData.append('lastName', lastName);
    userData.append('email', email);
    userData.append('position', position);
    userData.append('section', section);
    userData.append('department', department);
    userData.append('alias01', alias01);
    userData.append('alias02', alias02);
    userData.append('alias03', alias03);
    userData.append('alias04', alias04);
    userData.append('userPermissions', 'sa');
    userData.append('userGroup', 'sa');
    userData.append('userModifiedDate', userModifiedDate);
    userData.append('userModifiedBy', localStorage.getItem('username').toString());
    userData.append('userCreatedBy', localStorage.getItem('username'));
    
    this.http
    .post<{message: string, user: Users}>(
      BACKEND_URL, 
      JSON.stringify(userData),
      {headers: headers}
    )
    .subscribe((responseData) => {
      this.router.navigate(['user-list']);
    });
    console.log(userData)
  }
```

and this is the code from .net core

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<SyUsers>> PostSyUsers([FromBody]  SyUsers userData)
{
    _context.SyUsers.Add(userData);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetSyUsers", new { id = userData.Id }, userData);
}
```

on postman it is working:

[image: postman works]

Comment: Can you share your postman request body?

Comment: Use a plain javascript object instead of "FormData()":
const userData = {
authType: authType
...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postman, you encapsulate the data in the body, and the bakend is `[FromBody]`, so it can run correctly. But in angular, you use `FormData`, the receiving type is different.

Change `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]`, and remove the `JSON.stringify` in angular.

```
this.http
.post<{message: string, user: Users}>(
  BACKEND_URL, 

  userData,
  {headers: headers}
)
.subscribe((responseData) => {
  this.router.navigate(['user-list']);
});
```

[image]

Comment: @Christian Lacuesta, could you accept this answer?

Comment: yes thanks so much karney it was great help.